# c# SQLite how to store an object in a Dictionay with Field Name and field Value by id

Tags: c#, sqlite

First of all I assume that I am a beginner with SQLite, and there is probably a very simple way to solve my problem.

I have several class object in my program, Employee, Product, Customer etc all relaying on a parent "ObjectModel" class.
All of them are stored in a SQLite database.
What I am trying to do is to find a simple and fast way to store in a Dictionary a specific object, for instance Employee, who's Id is x :
so a simple request "`SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id_employee =x`";

and storing result

```
<id_employee, x>, 
<firstname, "Paul">, 
<lastname, "John"> 
etc etc etc.
```

The ExecuteReader Read() return each field value, but is there a function who could give me as both field name and field value ? And would allow me to build a function in my ObjectModel class who would retrieve a simple Object by Id ?

Thanks in advance for all suggestion.

Jeff

Comment: How are you storing the objects within your tables? - Serialized or in a Normalized form?

Comment: Normalized form each object in is own Row, autoincrement id. If that can help ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you please read this to improve your chances in the future to get better help? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically, it's better to add sample code (like the one from your own answer) to the question (you can easily edit the question to improve it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69.aspx) a command, the returned [reader object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx) allows you to directly read the column names and values:

```
var myemployeex = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(...))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    // replace "if" with "while" to get multiple rows
    if (reader.Read()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            employeex.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
            // replace GetValue with GetString if you really want strings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, i Found a solution, but maybe there is a much better way, I proceed my request in a DataTable like this :

```
string sqliteConnectionString = "Data Source=PATH OF MY SQLITE DATABSE"
string query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id_employee = x";

Dictionary<string, string> myemployeeX = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    SQLiteConnection db = DatabaseConnection(SqliteConnString);
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, db);
    db.Open();
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    adap.Fill(result);
    foreach(DataRow row in result.Rows) {
        foreach(DataColumn clmn in result.Columns) {
            myemployeeX.Add(clmn.ColumnName, row[clmn.ColumnName]);
        }
    }
    db.Close();
```

And it works, but I stay open for a more elegant or efficient solution.